# A non well formed numeric value encountered - shopping cart basket

Tags: php, laravel

I have the following message flagging up when notices are turned on:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcI4P.png

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Product;
use App\Cart;
use App\orders;
use DB;
use Auth;
class CartController extends Controller
{
    public function add(){
        $id = request('id');
        $product = Product::find($id);
    $oldCart = session()->has('cart') ? session()->get('cart') : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->add($product, $product->id);
    request()->session()->put('cart', $cart);
    return response()->json($cart->totalQty);
}
// public function add22(){
//     $id = request('id');
//     $product = Product::find($id);
//     $oldCart = session()->has('cart2') ? session()->get('cart2') : null;
//     $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
//     $cart->add($product, $product->id);
//     request()->session()->put('cart2', $cart);
//     return response()->json($cart->totalQty);
// }
public function add2($id) 
{
    $product = Product::find($id);      
    $oldCart = session()->has('cart') ? session()->get('cart') : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->add($product, $product->id);
    request()->session()->put('cart', $cart);       
    // dd(session()->get('cart'));

    return back();
}
public function index(){
    if(session()->has('cart'))
    {
        $products = session()->get('cart')->items;
    }
    // elseif(session()->has('cart2'))
    // {
    //     $products = session()->get('cart2')->items;
    // }
    else
    {
        $products = 'nothing';
    }
    $currency = DB::table('currency')->get();
    return view('basket', compact('products', 'currency'));
}
public function order(){
    if(session()->has('cart'))
    {
        $products = session()->get('cart')->items;
    }
    // elseif(session()->has('cart2'))
    // {
    //     $products = session()->get('cart2')->items;
    // }
    else
    {
        $products = 'nothing';
    }
    $currency = DB::table('currency')->get();
    return view('order', compact('products', 'currency'));
    // return view('order');
}
public function store(Request $request){
    $this ->validate(request(), [
        'name'=>'required',
        'address'=>'required',
        'auth'=>'required',
    ]);
    if(Auth::check())
    {
    $orders = orders::create([
        'name' => $request['name'],
        'description' => $request['address'],
        'auth' => $request['auth'],
    ]);
    }
    $cart = session()->get('cart');
    $message = "Имя: ".request('name')."\nАдрес:".request('address')."\nЗаказанные товары:";
    foreach($cart->items as $product) {
        $message .= $product['item']['name']." * ".$product['qty'].", Цена - ".$product['item']['entityprice']*$product['qty']."\n";
    }
    $message .= "\nИтого: ".$cart->totalPrice." тг\n";
    $subject = "Заказ товара";     
    $headers = 'From: info@hansolomed.kz' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: info@hansolome.kz' . "\r\n".
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    mail('015@i-marketing.kz', $subject, $message, $headers);
    request()->session()->forget('cart');
}    
public function remove($id){
    $oldCart = session()->has('cart') ? session()->get('cart') : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->removeItem($id);
    if(count($cart->items) > 0){
        session()->put('cart', $cart);
    }else{
        session()->forget('cart', $cart);
    }
    return redirect()->back();
}    
public function redis($id){
    $oldCart = session()->has('cart') ? session()->get('cart') : null;
    $cart = new Cart($oldCart);
    $cart->reduceByOne($id);
    session()->put('cart', $cart);
    return redirect()->back();        
}
```

}

Comment: I'd guess `$product` contains strings, not integers, so PHP must convert them to integers to do the math. The conversion throws that notice.

Comment: @user3783243 The conversion only throws a notice when the string is not numeric.

Answer (score 0):

I think user3783243 is right. Use floatval() or intval(), then you can multiply them.

```
<?php echo e(number_format( floatval( session()->get(cart)->totalPrice, 0, ',',' ')* floatval($currency[0]->coefficient) ; ?>
```

Comment: This might mask the notice but not fix the root of the problem, making it hard to debug. It's similar to masking notices by `@` operator. Somewhere a string seems to contain a non-numeric value. Imagine it is `'$50'` and it is handled as `0`

Comment: I asume, that the content is only in the wrong type, '20' instad of 20. Of course floatval() isn't for checking or sanitizing wrong inputs / values lik '$50'.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating with a `number_format` string that does not return a valid formatted number.

```
echo number_format(1000.95, 0, ',', ' ');
```

prints `1 001`.

`'1 001' * 2` throws a notice and calculates `2` (1*2), not `2001.90` as expected.

Your format means `0` decimals, `,` as decimal point and space as group of thousands separator. Use number formats only for output, do not calculate with formatted numbers.

You probably want:

```
echo e(number_format( session()->get(cart)->totalPrice * $currency[0]->coefficient , 2, ',', '' ));
```

Answer (score 0):

For the alternative https://github.com/bumbummen99/LaravelShoppingcart which is the forked project of https://github.com/Crinsane/LaravelShoppingcart and also support the latest Laravel versions.

There is a method called `Cart::totalFloat()` which will return your float value for the cart total.

############### OR #################

For this package just convert the number format back to integer or float values. An example is shown below

$num = '1,200,998.255';

########## FOR FLOAT VALUES ###########################

`echo filter_var($num, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);`

#output  : 1200998.255

########## FOR INTEGER VALUES ###########################

`echo filter_var($num, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);`

#output  : 1200998